# Visual Studio 13 c# вывод в textbox данных из ячейки таблицы БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, textbox

База данных создана в самом Visual, а вот как к ней обращаться и как вводить/выводить я не знаю, пожалуйста помогите хоть чем то! желательно синтаксисом ввода/вывода и куда его вводить!
БД имеет пока только одну таблицу:

[image: Файлы базы данных]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно самым простым способом отображать данные на форме это перетащить элементы из окна "Источники данных" на форму.

А вообще вот [Пошаговое руководство. Создание простого приложения для работы с данными](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171884.aspx)

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду DataGridView, то он не подходит для моего проекта, нужно отображение текста из одного поля, и его изменение по необходимости.

Comment: Нет, я не имею ввиду DataGridView. Попробуйте мышкой перетащить поле вашей таблицы, например поле Name, на форму вашего приложения. На форме автоматически создастся элемент управления для отображения и редактирования таблицы.

Comment: @Vyacheslav Если Вам помог какой-то из ответов, то Вы можете отметить его нажав на галочку. Это поможет другим участникам определить какой из ответов помог Вам в решении проблемы.